# Getting JSON data to populate a TableView from an Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I'm able to successfully populate the array with my JSON data inside of the loop, and I'm trying to populate the cells of my TableView with the same information, but currently the list comes up with no content.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    var headlines = [String]()
    let baseURL = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=123456789"



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        getJSON()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.table.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.table.dataSource = self
        self.table.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func getJSON() {

        let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                let SwiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
                let theTitle = SwiftyJSON["results"].arrayValue

                for title in theTitle{

                    let titles = title["title"].stringValue
                    self.headlines.insert(titles, atIndex: 0)
                    //print("- " + titles)
                }

                print(self.headlines)

            }

            else {
                print("there was an error")
            }
        }

        task.resume()

    }


    // From the UITAbleViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return headlines.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.headlines[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    // From the UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You tapped on cell # \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is asynchronous, so when you've loaded the array you have to reload your table

```
func getJSON() {

    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            let SwiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let theTitle = SwiftyJSON["results"].arrayValue

            for title in theTitle{

                let titles = title["title"].stringValue
                self.headlines.insert(titles, atIndex: 0)
                //print("- " + titles)
            }

            print(self.headlines)
            self.table.reloadData()
        }

        else {
            print("there was an error")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out with a friend a minute ago, I appreciate the help!